# Divide Weekly Budget by Workingdays

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I need to divide the weekly budget by the number of working days per week to get a daily target.
The budget table has a structure like:
Area - YearWeek - Budget

The calendar table contains the column "IsWorkingday" with the information regarding the factor (1 for working day)

The following measure is not working:

```
Budget Phasing = DIVIDE([Budget], SUM('Calendar'[IsWorkingDay]))
```

[Budget] is a measure that contains the weekly budget.

As you can see in the picture below I get a right value on weekly level.
But I need the same value on a daily level.
daily target  = Budget / SUM Workingdays

For example, for 25.05.2020 der should be 56.000 in der Budget Phasing

How can this be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Joshua, I think you are working with two tables - Budget and Calendar. Both tables are linked in my Data Model by [Week] column (which is a week number).

Try this measure, maybe this will help:

```
Budget Phasing = 
    var WeekNo = SELECTEDVALUE(tbl_Calendar[Week])
    var WorkingDays = CALCULATE(
        SUM(tbl_Calendar[IsWorkingDay]), 
        FILTER(ALL(tbl_Calendar), tbl_Calendar[Week] = WeekNo))
return
    DIVIDE([Budget], WorkingDays)
```

The result seems to match your requirements:

[image]